# PHP: PHP login and logou (set session path for  parent folder )

Tags: php

My login code is:

```
  session_start();
                if (isset($_COOKIE["cookiename"])){
                 $unm = $_SESSION["user_name"];
                  echo "User :  " . $_SESSION["user_name"] . "";
                  echo " <a href='http://localhost/UI/user/logout.php'>logout</a>";
                   echo " <a class='addmeeting' href='http://localhost/UI/user/createmeeting.php' title='Create New Meeting'>Create Meeting</a>";}

                else{
                  echo "<li><a href='register.php'>Register</a></li>";
                  echo " User : Guest!<br />";
                }
```

When the user is logged in, I want there to be a Logout link, and when they're not logged in, a Register link.

My files are as follows:

```
 UI
    user(folder)
       userprofile.php
       login.php
       logout.php  
    headers.php 
    index.php 
    footer.php
```

When I am logged in, it always shows Logout, except for on index.php. Outside of the user folder, however, it shows register.

What might be the problem here?
now i update my question

Comment: Use sessions for this, not cookies.

Comment: This is a very bad way to handle login, as one's might modify the cookie's value on his computer and therefore identify yourself as anybody without requiring any password.

Comment: FWIW: Since you're new to PHP, you may consider looking for a library that does logging in/logging out for you. It will make your life easy (and much more secure). Good luck

Comment: ok i will try but right now session is the only option ?

Comment: @david login/logout library ?

Comment: I recommand you to use a Framework like CodeIgniter, Symfony2, or CakePHP to make website with clean registration/authentication.

Comment: @Bgi, I almost recommend CodeIgniter! Alternatively, [this library](http://ulogin.sourceforge.net/) can be used with your from-scratch app.

Comment: @Bgi - If someone is new to programming then it is better for them to learn the fundamentals of a language first before diving into a framework where the fundamentals are hidden away and obscured.

Comment: i told you all i am from python background and have very less knowledge in php i am not able to handle MVC now because my project is almost completed

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined the cookie (with setcookie or something alike) from a script in the /user folder.

If you want the cookie to be avaiblable from other folders, you must set the $path parameter of the setcookie function:

[setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

But note using a cookie is a very bad idea to handle user authentication.