# PHP :Session is not working for parent directory

Tags: php

I have my code for setting the session like:

```
if($found>0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_name']=$user;

    session_set_cookie_params(24*60*1,'/','.localhost');

    $expire=time()+60*60*24;
    setcookie("cookiename", $user, $expire);

    header("location:http://localhost/UI/user/userprofile.php");
} else{
    $message =  "Username or  password is not correct.";
    header("Location:index.php?message={$message}");
}
```

here is my header content  where i put  login and logout

```
session_start();
if (isset($_COOKIE["cookiename"])){
    $unm = $_SESSION["user_name"];
    echo "User :  " . $_SESSION["user_name"] . "";
    echo " <a href='http://localhost/UI/user/logout.php'>logout</a>";
    echo " <a class='addmeeting' href='http://localhost/UI/user/createmeeting.php' title='Create New Meeting'>Create Meeting</a>";
} else{
    echo "<li><a href='register.php'>Register</a></li>";
    echo " User : Guest!<br />";
}
```

My session is working for subfolder but it is not working for the parent folder.
Here is the directory structure:

```
UI 
   user
      userprofile.php
      login.php
      logout.php 
   index.php
   headers.php
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: You **just** asked this.

Comment: you suggest me to use session i used that now i go through docs and i found session_set_cookie_params(24*60*1,'/','.localhost');
but still it is not working for me

Comment: @user1654711 - if you have a problem with a previous answer, the normal procedure here is to update the original question with any extra info required, rather than asking a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: PHP login and logou (set session path for  parent folder )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318327/php-php-login-and-logou-set-session-path-for-parent-folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it's the cookie that's not working, rather than the session (your session code is inside an `if()` block that checks the cookie first).

Cookies default to being limited to the current folder, so it won't apply to the parent folders.

If you want it to apply to the whole site, you need to specify a `/` in the cookie, like so:

```
setcookie("cookiename", $user, $expire, '/');
```

This will set the cookie across your entire site, so your code should work.

However, I don't really understand why you're not just using sessions here anyway; why have cookies and sessions in the same context? You may as well set everything in the session and be done with it. (sessions are cookie based anyway)

Comment: yeah its working now thanks and i will remove the cookie thanks for suggestion also